# converting a value to datetime in load csv in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, load-csv

I'm trying to load csv file into neo4j using this query:

```
:auto

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (news:newsID {newsID: row.id})
  ON CREATE SET 
  news.title = row.title, 
  news.creation_date = row.creation_date,
  news.content = row.content;
```

I want to convert `creation_date` to datetime
I can do that using something like:

```
WITH apoc.date.parse("2019-3-8 12:10:11", "ms", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") AS ms
RETURN datetime({epochmillis: ms}) as cdate
```

But I can not use it in the `LOAD CSV` set part.
How can I convert a field using `apoc.date.parse` and datetime in `LOAD CSV` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j can automatically parse a wide variety of [string formats to temporal instants](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-instants) (like `datetime`). You just have to use a supported string format.

Although your example string ("2019-3-8 12:10:11") is not supported, replacing the space character between the date and time with a "T" would work.

For example, try this:

```
RETURN datetime("2019-3-8T12:10:11");
```

So, *provided your `creation_date` property values had a supported format*, this would work:

```
:auto
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (news:newsID {newsID: row.id})
  ON CREATE SET 
  news.title = row.title, 
  news.creation_date = datetime(row.creation_date),
  news.content = row.content;
```

Or, if you want to keep your existing CSV file, and assuming its `creation_date` strings only have a single space character, you can do this:

```
:auto
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS row
MERGE (news:newsID {newsID: row.id})
  ON CREATE SET 
  news.title = row.title, 
  news.creation_date = datetime(REPLACE(row.creation_date, ' ', 'T')),
  news.content = row.content;
```